# How can i Handle alert message at the time of Save or if data is already Exist

Tags: robotframework, alert

Hi I am working for one site where i have to handle the popup window modal alert message for saving the data or showing data is already exist.

I am trying to insert one data which is already present so this time i have to compare the data already exist message with my code but i don't know how can i handle "Data saved successfully" and "Data already exist" condition in robot framework.

Comment: Reyansh, Is it correct to say, that an alert is shown if data already exists, but there is no alert if data is saved OK?

Comment: And may I put a thought about the question? You see, it is more common that the test case usually should know what it should expect when it does something. So, it could be a symptom of a flaw in test logic if the expected result is not defined.

Comment: Hi Sam let me explain with example. Suppose user is come on the page and enter country name as India and Currency as INR and click on save button so system will save the data but if another user comes to the same country master page and tried to save the data with same details like country as India and Currency as INR, so this it will through the alert as "data already exist". so i am trying to automate these conditions in one code but i am not able to handle both conditions. I tried with IF Else but didn't work.

Comment: So it possible to handle through robot framework that if system throws alert of data already exist then it will reload the page and after that verify the second condition instead of throwing error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems using [TRY-EXCEPT](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#try-except-syntax) block could be handy in your case. I.e. you could handle an alert in TRY block, and if your code reaches EXCEPT block it means there were no alert.

So, the prototype idea could look like

```
    TRY
        ${alert_text} =  handle alert  LEAVE  timeout=3s
    EXCEPT  Alert not found *    type=GLOB
        ${alert_text}  set variable  ${None}
    END

    IF  $alert_text is not None
        # actions if there is an alert 
    ELSE
        # actions for no alerts
    END
```